# How to find all this kind of UNICODE ï¿½ in multiple html pages (or, with notepad++)?

Tags: html, unicode, notepad++

how to find all this kind of UNICODE  `ï¿½` in multiple html pages?

using notepad++ or any other text editor :)

in this case, `ï¿½` is the same with `'`

Comment: Find them using what? For what purpose?

Comment: using notepad++ or any other text editor :)

Comment: What kind of Unicode, exactly, are you referring to?  Unicode encompasses literally every character you see on this webpage, or virtually any other webpage.

Comment: Press CTRL+F and search for the string

Comment: CTRL+F doesn't work, `ï¿½` is the same with `'`

Comment: `ï¿½` is a mis-decoded UTF-8 representation of U+FFFD (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER).  Since UTF-8 can encode any Unicode character, there is a least 3 levels of F-up decoding these pages.